# How can I have code looping while running other code in Python?

Tags: python

So I was wondering how to have two things running at once in Python 3.
Specifically, something like this:

```
import os
import time

def logo():
    os.system("cls")
    print("Logo")
    print("1")

    time.sleep(5)
    os.system("cls")
    print("Logo")
    print("2")

    time.sleep(5)
    logo()

def run():
    logo()
    # actual code of main program goes here

run()
```

Now, how can I use something like `logo()` which I want to loop constantly, but have my main program code still running and not ONLY the code from `logo()`, instead both at once?

Thanks!

Comment: You should look into python threading or multiprocessing.

Comment: You can use ```threading.Thread()```

Comment: Have you looked into multiprocessing or threading?

Answer (score 2):

As other have mentioned, try using threading.Thread().

This YouTube video does a pretty good job of explaining it as well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GqHLztqy0PU

For example:

```
import os
import time
import threading 
  
def logo1(): 
    print("Logo 1")
    print("1")
  
def logo2(): 
    print("Logo 2")
    print("2")
  
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    # create threads
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=logo1) 
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=logo2) 
    
    # start thread 1 
    t1.start() 
    # start thread 2 
    t2.start() 
    
    # wait until thread 1 is completely executed 
    t1.join() 
    # wait until thread 2 is completely executed 
    t2.join() 
    # both threads completely executed 
    
    print("Done!")
```

Comment: I upvoted this post, it does however not solve the exact problem of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Threads are things that can run at the same time. Python automatically starts the code in an automatically created thread called the "main thread" (or sometimes the same as the "ui thread").

`threading.Thread()` creates a new thread:

```
t = threading.Thread()
t.start()

# Do something
```

---

You'll need to use 2 threads: The main thread and a new one.

Use this code (I assume that you want to stop looping once your main program is done):

```
def logo(main_thread: Thread):
    # code
    if (main_thread.is_alive()) logo(main_thread)

def run():
    c = threading.current_thread()
    t = threading.Thread(target = logo, args = (c,))
    t.start()
    
    # do something else
```